# Dynamically creating a form

Tags: javascript, forms

On my page, I show a table of entries. At the end of the table is a "modify" button. When the button is clicked the row turns into a form for directly modifying the contents.

This code:

```
element.innerHTML = "<tr class='alt_col'>";
element.innerHTML += "<form action='/RIDT/includes/modify_codeplug.inc.php' method='POST' name='modify_form'>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' name='fileName' value='" + fileName + "'></td>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' name='location' value='" + loc + "'></td>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' name='build' value='" + build + "'></td>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' name='version' value='" + version + "'></td>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><select name='type' id ='selectType'>" + descOptions + "</select></td>";
element.innerHTML += "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + id + "'/><input type='submit' value='Submit'/></td>";
element.innerHTML += "</form>";
element.innerHTML += "</tr>";

var options = document.getElementById("selectType").options;

for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
{
    if (options[i].text == desc)
    {
        options[i].selected=true;
    }
}
```

Results in the form being created like this:

```
<form action="/RIDT/includes/modify_codeplug.inc.php" method="POST" name="modify_form"></form>
```

With all of the forms input elements coming after the closing  element. Why is the form being closed early?

Comment: Because you can't wrap a form around table data elements. That's invalid HTML and the browser attempts to correct it.

Comment: But I've done it on another page, and it does work. The code on the two pages now looks identical, but the problem remains.

Comment: I'll take that back. The other page has an "add new" form displayed as a table row. So there is no cell data present.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I will research all the suggestions provided more deeply later. In the interest of saving time I did it a different way. Instead of submitting a form, the submit button calls another javascript function that picks out the input data from the DOM, then builds and submits a hidden form to my php script. It's not pretty, but it got the job done.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this, but jQuery has the same problem if you try to insert an unclosed element into the DOM.  The closing tag is added for you.

Try this instead:

```
//track the html as a single string var
var html = "<tr class='alt_col'>";
html += "<form action='/RIDT/includes/modify_codeplug.inc.php' method='POST' name='modify_form'>";
html += "<td><input type='text' name='fileName' value='" + fileName + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' name='location' value='" + loc + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' name='build' value='" + build + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' name='version' value='" + version + "'></td>";
html += "<td><select name='type' id ='selectType'>" + descOptions + "</select></td>";
html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + id + "'/><input type='submit' value='Submit'/></td>";
html += "</form>";
html += "</tr>";

// set the html string once
element.innerHTML = html;
```